# Joomla 3 Bootstrap 3 only vertical

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

I'm working on my very first Joomla 3 & Bootstrap 3 site. The menu works excellent (dropdown perfect, hamburger works fine. But I can't figure out why all the menu items show up in a row under each other, rather than next to each other. As everything else works, I am fairly certain I put things in the wrong order.

This is the code in the template:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>    
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/"><?php echo $app->getCfg('sitename'); ?></a>
  </div>

  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-1" style="none" />
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    </ul>
  </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
</nav>
```

At the bottom of the page first *jquery.js* followed by *bootstrap.js*.

Thanks for the assist,

Jos

Comment: Hmm, the *html* you provided looks fine. Can you provide a link to your website as it might be a CSS related issue. It could be possible that a `float:left;` is missing in the CSS which will make the menu items appear next to each other

Comment: I found it. Simply adding a float:left in .nav > li

Comment: ahh good good, thought it might be something along those lines :)